# Use Github search API to find repos with name match and with specific file

Tags: api, github, search

I am trying to use the GitHub search API (on GH enterprise) to find certain repositories in my user account.  I am testing in my account, but will ultimately use this in an org.  I need find the repos that match all the following conditions:

- Repo is in `userid`
- Repo name starts with a specific `string`
- Repo has a specific `.file_name.yml` in the root

Referencing the GH API documentation, I have tried with the `repositories` and `code` api endpoints to no avail.

I know the search is working because:
`/api/v3/search/repositories?q=user:userid` and `/api/v3/search/repositories?q=string+user:Our-Org`
are working fine and returning the expected results.

When I try to add the filename is where it starts to fall apart.

- `/api/v3/search/repositories?q=string+user:userid+filename:.file_name.yml`
- `/api/v3/search/repositories?q=string+user:userid+path:.file_name.yml`
- `/api/v3/search/repositories?q=string+user:userid+path:/.file_name.yml`
- `/api/v3/search/repositories?q=string+user:userid+path:/.file_name.yml`

All these return zero results, on the `repository1 endpoint aswell as the`code` endpoint. :(